# Problem lookDevs blender 2.8 mode

Tags: rendering

I have a problem, when I put in Lookdevs everything is dark, even having light in the scene, it appears the changes only when active up there, the option "Scene Ligths, but the reflections do not appear, I do not know how to solve, here Here's a print to better understand: [image]

In the tutorial in question, it looks like this:
[image]

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There's are 2 things that affect overall lighting in the scene

- lights
- world

The Look Dev viewport shading allows you to see what your objects would look like in predefined lighting conditions.  This is configurable to allow standard studio lighting setups which can be useful when modeling and animating.

You can override both the scene lights and the scene world to use the lighting from your scene.

In the general case, and unless you know what you are doing you should leave both boxes **unchecked** (as shown in the screenshot below).

Now, there is one other thing which may cause a problem.  If this is very small then the amount of ambient light will be low and you will have a dark Look Dev setup. Make sure that the **world strength** setting is something sensible (probably 1.0)

[image: Viewport Shading Options]

I hope this helps, there's a lot of learning in blender, but also a lot of fun too.

Comment: Even with both turned off, it's still dark, and my "Strenght" option doesn't appear, so I don't know, Look:  https://imgur.com/undefined

Comment: Sorry I was running 2.81 beta at the time so that explains the difference.  Not sure what it could be.  Edit your question and upload your blend file, I'll take a loook when I get a chance.